# Multiple SingleThreadExecutors for a given application...a good idea?

Tags: java, multithreading, pool

This question is about the fallouts of using `SingleThreadExecutor` (JDK 1.6). Related questions have been asked and answered in this forum before, but I believe the situation I am facing, is a bit different.

Various components of the application (let's call the components C1, C2, C3 etc.) generate (outbound) messages, mostly in response to messages (inbound) that they receive from other components. These outbound messages are kept in queues which are usually `ArrayBlockingQueue` instances - fairly standard practice perhaps. However, the outbound messages must be *processed* in the order they are added. I guess use of a `SingleThreadExector` is the obvious answer here. We end up having a 1:1 situation - *one* `SingleThreadExecutor` for *one* queue (which is dedicated to messages emanating from *one* component).

Now, the number of components (C1,C2,C3...) is unknown at a given moment. They will come into existence depending on the need of the users (and will be eventually disposed of too). We are talking about 200-300 such components at the peak load. Following the 1:1 design principle stated above, we are going to arrange for 200 `SingleThreadExecutor`s. This is the source of my query here.

I am uncomfortable with the thought of having to create so many *SingleThreadExecutor*s. I would rather try and use a **pool of SingleThreadExecutor**s, if that makes sense and is plausible (any ready-made, seen-before classes/patterns?). I have read many posts on recommended use of `SingleThreadExecutor` here, but what about a pool of the same?

What do learned women and men here think? I would like to be directed, corrected or simply, admonished :-).

Comment: Is the order requirement global or per-component?

Comment: Good question and sorry, I didn't clarify that. Order requirement is per-component.

Answer (score 2):

If your requirement is that the messages be processed in the order that they're posted, then you want one and only one `SingleThreadExecutor`. If you have multiple executors, then messages will be processed out-of-order across the set of executors.

If messages need only be processed in the order that they're received *for a single producer*, then it makes sense to have one executor per producer. If you try pooling executors, then you're going to have to put a lot of work into ensuring affinity between producer and executor.

Since you indicate that your producers will have defined lifetimes, one thing that you have to ensure is that you properly shut down your executors when they're done.

Comment: Thanks. That 'lot of work' part in your reply was the source of my discomfiture. Even if I can manage to do, having 200 SingleThreadPoolExecutors may not be a good idea. What do you think?

Comment: My "lot of work" comment was actually a suggestion that the 200 executors is the *correct* way to go ... provided that you can't use a single executor. But only you can know the actual requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Messaging and batch jobs is something that has been solved time and time again.  I suggest not attempting to solve it again.  Instead, look into Quartz, which maintains thread pools, persisting tasks in a database etc.  Or, maybe even better look into JMS/ActiveMQ.  But, at the very least look into Quartz, if you have not already.  Oh, and Spring makes working with Quartz so much easier...

Comment: Quartz is surely worth a look. Thanks. JMS is too heavy for the kind of application I am involved with; deployment characteristics of the application are deterrents to use of Spring.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem there. Essentially you have independent queues and each has to be drained sequentially, one thread for each is a natural design. Anything else you can come up with are essentially the same. As an example, when Java NIO first came out, frameworks were written trying to take advantage of it and get away from the thread-per-request model. In the end some authors admitted that to provide a good programming model they are just reimplementing threading all over again.

Comment: Thanks, but is this a good design to have a bunch of SingleThreadPoolExecutors (to the tune of 300 at the peak time) - that is the question. This arrangement certainly keeps matters much simple for me, but would you approve of that from (eventual) performance/scalability point of view? 

Many thanks for taking time to reply.

Comment: 200 threads shouldn't be a problem for a single machine. if you want more robust and scalable solution, you need a distributed architecture, existing frameworks for such purposes should be looked at.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say whether 300 or even 3000 threads will cause any issues without knowing more about your application. I strongly recommend that you should profile your application before adding more complexity

The first thing that you should check is that number of concurrently running threads should not be much higher than number of cores available to run those threads. The more active threads you have, the more time is wasted managing those threads (context switch is expensive) and the less work gets done.

The easiest way to limit number of running threads is to use semaphore. Acquire semaphore before starting work and release it after the work is done.

Unfortunately limiting number of running threads may not be enough. While it may help, overhead may still be to great, if time spent per context switch is major part of total cost of one unit of work. In this scenario, often the most efficient way is to have fixed number of queues. You get queue from global pool of queues when component initializes using algorithm such as round-robin for queue selection.

If you are in one of those unfortunate cases where most obvious solutions do not work, I would start with something relatively simple: one thread pool, one concurrent queue, lock, list of queues and temporary queue for each thread in pool.

Posting work to queue is simple: add payload and identity of producer.

Processing is relatively straightforward as well. First you get get next item from queue. Then you acquire the lock. While you have lock in place, you check if any of other threads is running task for same producer. If not, you register thread by adding a temporary queue to list of queues. Otherwise you add task to existing temporary queue. Finally you release the lock. Now you either run the task or poll for next and start over depending on whether current thread was registered to run tasks. After running the task, you get lock again and see, if there is more work to be done in temporary queue. If not, remove queue from list. Otherwise get next task. Finally you release the lock. Again, you choose whether to run the task or to start over.